# Why does Process.Start throw Win32Exception if using different user credentials?

Tags: c#, process

I need to start a process as another user and it's bombing.

I scaled it down my code to a simple reference example.  This code works fine to start the process itself:

```
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
                       {
                           UseShellExecute = false,
                           RedirectStandardInput = true,
                           RedirectStandardError = true,
                           RedirectStandardOutput = true
                       };
```

However, if I add the `UserName` and `Password` values:

```
       var info = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
                       {
                           UserName = "user",
                           Password = StringToSecureString("password"),
                           UseShellExecute = false,
                           RedirectStandardInput = true,
                           RedirectStandardError = true,
                           RedirectStandardOutput = true
                       };
        Process.Start(info);
```

It bombs with the ever so helpful System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception message:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Just in case, here is the secure string conversion method:

```
    private static SecureString StringToSecureString(string s)
    {
        var secure = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in s.ToCharArray())
        {
            secure.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return secure;
    }
```

Any ideas or alternate solutions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your code works for me, so the problem is not with the actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your `Secondary Logon` service started, I believe this is required to start a new process under a different user account?

Comment: The give-a-away is that there error is telling you that it's looking for a "service" that it cannot start. ;)

Comment: See, you say "give-away" and I say "confusing as hell".  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably missing the `Domain` property on the `ProcessStartInfo`.

Compare your code to the example given in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx):

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Instantiate the secure string.
        SecureString securePwd = new SecureString();
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;

        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        do {
           key = Console.ReadKey(true);

           // Ignore any key out of range.
           if (((int) key.Key) >= 65 && ((int) key.Key <= 90)) {
              // Append the character to the password.
              securePwd.AppendChar(key.KeyChar);
              Console.Write("*");
           }   
        // Exit if Enter key is pressed.
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.WriteLine();

        try
        {
            Process.Start("Notepad.exe", "MyUser", securePwd, "MYDOMAIN");
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have specified that I tried with Domain too.  Same result.

Comment: FWIW, once I enabled the Secondary Logon service it worked without the Domain.